# В имени файла есть пробел, как эффективно его удалить с помошью bat?

Tags: bat

Имя по типу "name_ 02227.log".
Eсть пробел между "_" и "0". Присутствует он не всегда. Как удалить?

Я хотел создать проверку на пробел, но она не работает:

```
SET str=" 0122017"
IF %str:~0,1%==" " (SET str=%str:~1%)
```

ошибка:

> " (SET str= 0122017") was unexpected at this time.

Comment: так и удаляйте...

Comment: Хочу сделать это автоматически, а не руками. фалов генерируеться много.

Comment: 1) Вот зачем кавычки в первом SET? не бывает кавычек **в имени файла**. 2) Не для BAT/CMD задачка-то, лучше на VBS выполнить требуемое.

Comment: А что там можно поставить? Я из мира Java, я замечаю что строки работают совсем по другому в батах. Для меня не понятно в чем тут проблема. Имя фала генерируеться в bat-e и мне нужно его изменить там же. Это невозможно?

Comment: Мне тружно представить, что он не может справиться с такой легкой залдачей.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting Недавно как раз кому-то советовал эту книжку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильный вызова обработки текста удалением пробелов в примере.

```
SET str=" 0122017"
set str=%str: =%
echo %str%
```